# How can I make IIS redirect the request back to browser , rather than application redirecting it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have created `asp.net mvc` application which is deployed in a virtual machine's `IIS`

Application is enabled for Microsoft authentication through `Active Directory` and redirect is happening without any issues.

However, request is hitting the application layer. Is it possible to redirect from IIS itself, rather than request hitting the application?

**Flow**

1. Browser sends unauthenticated request to server
2. Application sees that request does not have valid token and rejects the request
3. rejected request comes back to the browser, and browser sends it to `AAD` for token

Need help in rejecting the request at stpe 2, by IIS rather than application. Is there any IIS module help here?

Expectation drawing is below

[image]

Comment: AAD works that way. IIS does not support AAD natively, so you won't get any redirection by it.

Comment: I agree, however, can IIS reject the unauthenticated requests by looking in to request headers?

Comment: You can refer to this article [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb470252(v=vs.100)) to get its request flow.